# Crashlytics React-Native app distribution doesn't go pass splash screen

Tags: react-native, crashlytics, crashlytics-android, crashlytics-beta

I have followed the installation process to use Crashlytics to distribute my React Native app. When I have archived and installed the app via Beta, app stuck at Splash Screen and doesnt go passed it (This issue is in both iOS and Andriod). Does anyone had this issue before. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. We don't officially support React Native apps. I know many devs would like to see it added though.